# KONTAKT scripting - Tutorials & videos

Tags: dvd, tutorial, kontakt, script, books

I would really like to learn kontakt scripting. can anybody suggest books or dvds based on basic kontakt scripting as i have no knowledge in scripting or coding in general.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party but you can find a full series of Kontakt scripting tutorial videos here: http://xtant-audio.com/store/products/73 Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm in kindergarten....

a book: (not recent)
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/3839150515/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3839150515)

a site:
http://www.kontakttutorials.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another good beginners resource is:

http://www.nilsliberg.se/ksp/scripts/tutorial/

Or from NI themselves:

http://www.audiotek.cz/produktyATK/ni/kontakt3_p2.pdf

Or

http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jul10/articles/kontakt1.htm

Or

http://www.askaudiomag.com/articles/introduction-to-scripting-in-kontakt-part-1

I'll stop at this point, but a bit of a basic research would have uncovered these!!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start is to read the basics on Nils Liberg site (http://nilsliberg.se/ksp/scripts/tutorial/) and follow VI-Control Kontakt Scripting section of their forum (http://www.vi-control.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=65)

Cheers,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

I've also searched for this info on scripts in Kontakt.  This is the only thing that I found:

http://www.soniccouture.com/en/products/p50-scriptorium-tutorial-videos/

Its a start anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are some videos here. I'm not sure how useful they will be. - 
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Kontakt+scripting&sm=3

Answer (score 0):

Last week I found [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/KSP-Scripting-1-Mike-Novy/dp/3839150515) on KSP written by Mike Snow.
And this [online course](http://xtant-audio.com/category/tutorial-videos-kontakt) also seems nice.

Comment: Your answer is a bit minimal. Can you share some of your experience with the book and online course?

Comment: Recently I've been looking for good resources on ksp myself, because I want to make my own instruments. I found this book after a long search. haven't bought it yet but it seems a very good (and rare) source to ksp-programming.